# If I have one variable as int, and use it for calculating other of type float, why is result shown as rounded-down float?

Tags: c, type-conversion, printf

I'm doing an equation solver. The code goes like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Equation solver of type ax + by = 0, for y\n");
    int a, b, x;
    float y;
    printf("Enter value of a as integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter value of b as integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Enter value of x as integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    y = a*x/b; //We have equation ax + by = 0, from that: ax = by, and that is: y = ax/b
    printf("Solution for y of equation: %dx + %dy = 0, for x = %d, is: %.2f", a, b, x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

When I enter a = 3, b = 5 and x = 3, the output is supposed to be 1.80, but I get 1.00. Why is this? Wouldn't expression a*x/b be converted into type of float? I'm just beginner and we only mentioned type conversion with our professor, maybe I got it wrong?

Comment: But wouldn't that automatically be done by compiler?

Comment: Nope. There are rules for when implicit conversion happens. I added a good link to my answer.

Comment: mihajlo2, "Wouldn't expression a*x/b be converted into type of float?" --> Yes, the result of  `a*x/b` (which is 1) is converted to `float` (no rounding down occurred) _after_ an `int` multiplication `a*x` and after an `int` division.

Comment: @mihajlo2 Why does code use `float` and not `double`?  Who or what text suggested `float`?

Comment: @mihajlo2 I added a more exensive walkthrough of what happens to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `a*x/b` all variables are `int`s so it's a pure integer calculation.

If you cast one of the first operands used to `float`, the other will also be implicitly converted to `float`

```c
y = (float) a * x / b;
```

More about what implicit conversions there are can be found here:
[Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

---

Broken down according to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence):

| Precedence | Operator | Description | Associativity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | `*` `/` `%` | Multiplication, division, and remainder | Left-to-right |
| 14 | `=` | Simple assignment | Right-to-left |

```
y = a*x/b; // with a = 3, b = 5 and x = 3
```

According to operator precedence, `a*x` will be performed first and as can be read in the [Usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) chapter on *Implicit conversions*:
*"The arguments of the following arithmetic operators `[*, /, %, +, -, ...]` undergo implicit conversions for the purpose of obtaining the common real type, **which is the type in which the calculation is performed**"*

If *"both operands are integers. Both operands undergo [integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions)"*. Since both `a` and `x` are `int` - no promotion is necessary and the *common type* is therefore `int` and the calculation is done using `int`s:

```
3 * 3 => 9
```

Next according to operator precedence comes the result of `a*x` divided by `b`. Again, `b` is an `int` and `9` is an `int` so the same procedure as above gives us `int` as the common type.

```
9 / 5 => 1
```

The last step according to operator precedence is the simple assignment `y = 1`. In the chapter *"Conversion as if by assignment"* we can read:
*"In the assignment operator, the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the unqualified type of the left-hand operand."*

This means that it's only now that the result of the calculation, `1`, becomes `1.f` (`float`)

```
1 => 1.f
```

and that's what's assigned to `y`.

By converting `a` to `float`, like in `y = (float) a * x / b;`, you can follow the rules for finding the *common type* and see that `x` will be converted to `float` and then `b`, so the calculation becomes `3.f * 3.f / 5.f` and the result will be `1.8f`.

If you are sure that `a * x` will not cause integer overflow (~produce a value that is too large or small to store in an `int`), you can delay the conversion until the division:

```
y = a * x / (float) b;
```

It will now do an integer multiplication and only then will the result of that multiplication be converted to `float` and divided by `5.f`, as if done like so:

```
y = (float) (3 * 3) / 5.f;
```

Answer (score 3):

> Wouldn't expression a*x/b be converted into type of float?

The **result** of that expression gets converted to `float` before being assigned to `y`.  Since each operand has type `int`, the math is done with that type.

Specifically, `a*x` and `b` both have type `int`, so integer division is performed which truncates the fractional part.

If you cast one of the variables to type `float`, then floating point division will be performed.

```
y = (float)a*x/b;
```